# Dual of module isomorphic to module itself?

Tags: modules, duality-theorems

If $A$ is a finitely generated $B$-module, is it true that dual of $A$ is isomorphic to $A$,i.e.,$Hom(A,B)\cong A$?

I guess given $f \in Hom(A,B)$, if $f(a)=1$, then I can identify $f$ to $a$. Am I right?

Comment: It will very rarely happen that such an $f$ exists; e.g. if $B=\mathbb{Z}$, and $A$ is a finite abelian group, $\hom(A,B) = 0$

Comment: Thank you for your example. But now if $A$ is a finitely generated $B$-module , is that statement right?

Comment: A finite abelian group is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$ module, as a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$ module is precisely a finitely generated abelian group, and finite groups are certainly finitely generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false in general. Indeed, take the $\mathbb Z$ module $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for $n \geq 2 $. While $|\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z| = n$, one can show that there is exactly one group homomorphism (i.e. $\mathbb Z$-linear map) $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z$, which is the zero morphism. Thus, these modules are certainly not isomorphic.

Indeed, such a map is determined entirely by its image on 1 and exists if and only if 1 is sent to an element $a \in \mathbb Z$ such that $na = 0$, and the only such $a$ is $0$. This is because of the universal property of quotients of $R$ modules, which states that an $R$ linear map $M \longrightarrow M'$ which vanishes on a submodule $N \subseteq M$ factors uniquely through $M/N$.

The result is, however, true for free modules of finite rank by the same proof as the vector space case.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But how could the the proof of vector spaces be applied to free modules of finite rank? The ring of coefficient may not be division ring, thus free modules may not be identical to vector spaces.

Comment: The same proof works because the essential element of the proof was the existence of bases, not the divisibility of the coefficients. That was just a mechanism that allowed bases to exist, but bases were the key. Note, however, that not all properties of vector spaces extend to free modules. For example, the quotient of vector spaces is a vector space (hence free), but the quotient of free modules is not (take $\mathbb Z /2 \mathbb Z $).

Comment: I got your point, thanks!